# Shorten a string containing data

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am creating an application to create a key that is unique to each computer. This info is derived from the OS serial number and processorID.

Is there a way to 'shorten' a string? Maybe by converting it to HEX or something else...

The reason is this: I used to use a VB6 section of code (http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb...48926&lngWId=1) that gets the details and the output is only 13 digits long. Mine is a lot longer, but gets the same info...

BTW, the link I posted above won multiple awards, but I am having huge trouble in converting it to .NET. Has anyone by any chance converted it, or know of someone who has? Or a tool that actually works?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the full working link: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=48926&lngWId=1

Comment: your link in above is trimmed off and can not get the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a 'hashing algorithm' or 'hash function'. They are a common concept: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Generally speaking you can simply write your own function to take a string and return a hashed number but there is some suitable code here that uses the .NET framework: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301053

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example which retrieves the Processor ID, for the first Processor found, and the OS Serial Number; it concatenates these to strings together and then performs various encodings on them.

This is a simple VB.Net Console project. Be sure to reference the **System.Management** assembly in your project. Just copy and paste this code example into the main module, set a breakpoint at the end of Sub Main(), and look at the various results.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim uniqueID As String = GetUniqueID()

        ' convert it to a base64 string
        Dim encoding As New Text.ASCIIEncoding()
        Dim result1 = Convert.ToBase64String(encoding.GetBytes(uniqueID))

        ' compress it
        Dim result2 As String = CompressString(uniqueID)
        Dim result3 As String = DecompressString(result2)

        ' encrypt it
        Dim result4 As String = AES_Encrypt(uniqueID, "password")
        Dim result5 As String = AES_Decrypt(result4, "password")

        ' hash it
        Dim result6 As String = HashString(uniqueID)
    End Sub

    Private Function GetUniqueID() As String
        Dim result As String = GetOSSerialNumber()
        Dim processorIDs() As String = GetProcessorIDs()
        If ((processorIDs IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (processorIDs.Count > 0)) Then
            result &= processorIDs(0)
        End If
        Return result
    End Function

    Private Function GetProcessorIDs() As String()
        Dim result As New List(Of String)
        Dim searcher = New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select ProcessorId from Win32_Processor")
        For Each managementObj In searcher.Get()
            result.Add(CStr(managementObj.Properties("ProcessorId").Value))
        Next
        Return result.ToArray()
    End Function

    Private Function GetOSSerialNumber() As String
        Dim result As String = ""
        Dim searcher = New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select SerialNumber from Win32_OperatingSystem")
        For Each managementObj In searcher.Get()
            result = CStr(managementObj.Properties("SerialNumber").Value)
        Next
        Return result
    End Function

    Public Function CompressString(ByVal source As String) As String
        Dim result As String = ""
        Dim encoding As New Text.ASCIIEncoding()
        Dim bytes() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(source)
        Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream
            Using gzsw As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress)
                gzsw.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
                gzsw.Close()
                result = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return result
    End Function

    Public Function DecompressString(ByVal source As String) As String
        Dim result As String = ""
        Dim bytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(source)
        Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(bytes)
            Using gzsw As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
                Dim data(CInt(ms.Length)) As Byte
                gzsw.Read(data, 0, CInt(ms.Length))
                Dim encoding As New Text.ASCIIEncoding()
                result = encoding.GetString(data)
            End Using
        End Using
        Return result
    End Function

    Public Function AES_Encrypt(ByVal input As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
        Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
        Dim Hash_AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
        Dim encrypted As String = ""
        Try
            Dim hash(31) As Byte
            Dim temp As Byte() = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass))
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
            AES.Key = hash
            AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
            Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor
            Dim Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)
            encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return encrypted
    End Function

    Public Function AES_Decrypt(ByVal input As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
        Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
        Dim Hash_AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
        Dim decrypted As String = ""
        Try
            Dim hash(31) As Byte
            Dim temp As Byte() = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass))
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
            AES.Key = hash
            AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
            Dim DESDecrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateDecryptor
            Dim Buffer As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(input)
            decrypted = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(DESDecrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return decrypted
    End Function

    Private Function HashString(ByVal source As String) As String
        Dim encoding As New Text.ASCIIEncoding()
        Dim bytes() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(source)
        Dim workingHash() As Byte = New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(bytes)
        Dim result As String = ""
        For Each b In workingHash
            result = result & b.ToString("X2")
        Next
        Return result
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks Randy. If I hash a String, can I 'unhash' it to get the original string?

Comment: Hash functions are not reversible.